# Angular 5 NullInjectorError: No provider for n

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, production

When I'm starting my website with `ng serve` everything works fine, but every try to launch a production getting an error `NullInjectorError: No provider for n`. I checked all services that I wrote are included in NgModule providers. Because this is the production, all files are minified and uglified, so I don't know what exactly cause the problem. Is there any way to check it or maybe it's possible to get from the error details?

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(G)[n -> n]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
at n.get (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
at main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1
at n (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
at n.get (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
at main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1
at n (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
at n.get (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
at Pi (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
at main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1
at Li (main.94f42881e2fdceca85d7.bundle.js:1)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is probably due to the differences of `JIT` (just-in-time) and `AOT` (ahead-of-time) compiler. Read more about this in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

If you run `ng serve` or `ng build` it will use `JIT` by default. With the `--prod` flag however, `AOT` is used.

Try running `ng serve --aot` or `ng serve --prod` to see a more comprehensible error message. Since this is not much slower any more, I'd recommend always using the `--aot` flag during development. You will see problems much earlier.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, what worked for me was adding HttpClientModule to imports in the app root module. What causes the error was that i imported in another module.

```
// app.module.ts
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
imports: [HttpClientModule]
})
```